# Geocoded Points Don't Land Directly On Street

Tags: spatial-join, interpolation, geocoding, streets

ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2

My street locator includes a street feature class that has streets ranges for the Left and Right side of the street (Left Start, Left End, Right Start, Right End). The street feature class has the role set as StreetAddress.

I set the offsets to 0, so I was expecting the points to land directly on the street feature class lines.

However, they seem to land about 1ft off (some are 1ft, some are half a ft, some are 1.25 ft etc.), which impacts some tools later down the line which do an intersect spatial join with the points and streets.

Is there a way to fix this? Or is it intended behavior from ESRI interpolation?

[image: Screnshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]